# How to draw two arc path without connect line?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, cgpath

I'm using `CGMutablePath` to draw a wifi logo. When I draw the second arc by   `addArc(center:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:transform:)`, it will automatically draw a line like the document specified `If the path already contains a subpath, this method adds a line connecting the current point to the starting point of the arc.`. How can I draw without this line? Thanks

Comment: Move the point.

Comment: @ElTomato so I have to calculate the start point of next arc path and move to next point?

Comment: I don't know exactly since you don't show a single line of code.  But isn't it just the matter of moving the arc center?  Plus, I'm not really an iOS person.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to draw an arc without the line from the previous point you need to move the path to the start of the arc—using `move(to:)`— before adding the arc. The start of the arc can be calculated as:

```
center.x + radius * cos(startAngle)
center.y + radius * sin(startAngle)
```

Rather than calculating the points to create the outline of each arc yourself, you can leverage CGPath's ability to create a stroke copy. Doing this, you only need to create the base path with one arc for each "bar" of the icon:

```
let basePath = CGMutablePath()

let center     = CGPoint.zero
let startAngle = CGFloat.pi * 0.75 // 135 degrees
let endAngle   = CGFloat.pi * 0.25 //  45 degrees

let radii: [CGFloat] = [10, 20, 30, 40]

for radius in radii {
    // Move to the start point of the arc
    basePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(startAngle),
                              y: center.y + radius * sin(startAngle)))
    // Add the arc, starting at that same point
    basePath.addArc(center: center, radius: radius,
                    startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle,
                    clockwise: true)
}
```

This creates a base shape like this, without any thickness:

[image: Base path]

Next, you create a copy of the base path by stroking it. Here you can configure the thickness of the icon's bars and the style of their ends (square or rounded):

```
let stroked = basePath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 5, // The width/thickness of each stroked arc
                            lineCap: .square,     // Make square corners for the ends of each arc
                            lineJoin: .miter, miterLimit: 0)
```

Resulting in a shape like this:

[image: Stroked path]

Comment: Excellent answer. (voted.) Did you write that code for this question, or have it on hand?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your example code is written to assume that the center-point of all the arcs is CGPoint.zero. Wouldn't it be more useful to write it to use an arbitrary center point?

Comment: I modified some Bezier path code I already had at hand and took screenshots of UIBezierPath previews in that playground.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, El Tomato told you what you need to do. Since `addArc(center:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:transform:)` draws a line from the last point in your path to the start of the arc, you need to use `move(to:transform:)` to first move to the new arc's beginning point before adding it.

It would be nice if `addArc(center:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:transform:)` took a flag that controlled whether it drew a line to it's starting point or not, but it doesn't seem to.

Calculating the starting point will involve a little trig.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `move(to:transform:)` before adding the second arc. See more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/2427143-move).